Can't change the display resolution on Ubuntu 22.04
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Lenovo Legion Slim 5 16APH8
Graphics Processor:
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU
$ nvidia-smi

Sat Aug 10 11:42:57 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.107.02             Driver Version: 550.107.02     CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   34C    P8              2W /   60W |    1098MiB /   8188MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3027      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            430MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3223      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          193MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6042      G   ...erProcess --variations-seed-version         66MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9517      G   ...seed-version=20240808-180127.171000        187MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12565      G   ...sktop/6088/usr/bin/telegram-desktop         87MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19512      G   ...irefox/4698/usr/lib/firefox/firefox         16MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     22113      G   ...yOnDemand --variations-seed-version         92MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     52741      G   gnome-control-center                            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     53718      G   nvidia-settings                                 0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I can't change the screen resolution in the standard way, through the settings. The available resolution is only 2560x1600(16x10) and there is no way to change it.
I try using the NVIDIA X Server Settings:
$ sudo nvidia-settings


Open the NVIDIA X Server Settings application
Go to "X Server Display Configuration"
Change the resolution there
Save configuration file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

However, after restarting the PC, the screen extension returns to 2560x1600(16x10).
UPD. OpenAI advised to perform a reinstallation:
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ Copysudo apt purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

However, after these manipulations, I can no longer adjust the brightness. The slider is there and moves, but nothing changes. :(
$ nvidia-smi

Tue Aug 13 09:42:04 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 555.58.02              Driver Version: 555.58.02      CUDA Version: 12.5     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   32C    P8              3W /   60W |     614MiB /   8188MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2988      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            253MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3182      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          141MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5787      G   ...erProcess --variations-seed-version         63MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6805      G   ...seed-version=20240812-050059.636000        129MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

When I run
$ sudo nvidia-settings

CRITICAL appears:
(nvidia-settings:10858): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:43:50.136: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 09:43:50.402: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 09:43:50.402: PRIME: is it supported? no

UPD 26.08.2024
I managed to fix the brightness settings
source 1
source 2
with setting kernel parameter:
nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1

Tried the drivers from this list 545-560, the result is his own.
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-driver-535-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-555, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-555)
nvidia-driver-545, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545)
nvidia-driver-545-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545-open)
nvidia-driver-560-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-560-open)
nvidia-driver-560, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-560)
nvidia-driver-535-server-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-550, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-550-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-555-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-555-open)

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:...

It is not possible to change the screen resolution through the settings. nvidia-settings are not saved resolution when restarting the laptop.
For now, I left the newest version of driver
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX Open Kernel Module for x86_64  560.35.03  Release Build  (dvs-builder@U16-I1-N07-12-3)  Fri Aug 16 21:42:42 UTC 2024
GCC version:  gcc version 12.3.0 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)



$ nvidia-smi
Mon Aug 26 20:29:46 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P8              2W /   60W |     284MiB /   8188MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3064      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            162MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3260      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           98MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5782      G   gnome-control-center                            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I will try to update to Ubuntu 24.04 later. Perhaps such an extreme decision will solve the situation.

Are you using X.org or Wayland? If you are using Wayland it will ignore any X server settings.

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
$ loginctl show-session $(loginctl | grep $(whoami) | awk '{print $1}') -p Type
Type=x11


Don't use AI tools. They're not helpful. 2. You have not shown the output, only the commands, with a typo in. 3. Now you have an older driver. This is an example of why the bot's advice was bad. 4. Get the latest driver from nVidia and install it.


I asked on the Lenovo forums for users, maybe they will clarify something there
